# React.js App Login with Google, Error "idpiframe_initialization_failed"

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-signin, react-google-login

I am implementing Login with Google for my react.js application. I have followed the steps from this tutorial video: https://youtu.be/75aTZq-qoZk.

I am running my app from http://localhost:3000, I have registered it with my client Id at Google Cloud Platform under "Authorised JavaScript origins" heading. However, I am still getting this error:

```
{
    "error": "idpiframe_initialization_failed",
    "details": "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost:3000 has not been registered for client ID. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and register this origin for your project's client ID."
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';

export default class Login extends Component {

    googleLoginSuccess = (googleData) => {
        console.log("Success", googleData);
    }

    googleLoginFailure = (result) => {
        console.log("Failure", result)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <GoogleLogin
                clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
                buttonText="Login"
                onSuccess={this.googleLoginSuccess}
                onFailure={this.googleLoginFailure}
                cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding the "localhost" in the left side bar -> "Authentication" -> "Sign in method" -> "Autorised domains"

Comment: The error message details tell you exactly what to do - did you follow those instructions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it in an incognito tab,

Try to re-create your credentials,

Make sure you're not using https by accident,

also:

> Note: It may take 5 minutes to a few hours for settings to take effect

Comment: It worked after a few hours. Your note helped.

Comment: Glad it worked out!